# Flexible word count in Pytorch Embedding

Tags: pytorch, embedding

The [Embedding](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Embedding.html#torch.nn.Embedding) class in Pytorch takes in *num_embedding* as a parameter. According to the doc, num_embedding is "size of the dictionary of embeddings". I am curious about the following two cases when creating an embedding object:

1. The num_embedding, or word count in a database, is unknown before we
   create an embedding.
2. The num_embedding, or word count, is flexible.
   For example, initially I create an embedding with num_embedding, or
   word count, 1000. Later I have some new elements added in. For
   example, I have 10 new words on top of the existing 1000 words, how
   to modify the existing embedding (keep the embedding_dim same) to
   adapt the change?

Comment: For `nn.Embedding` you can't. The Embedding layer needs to initiate the weights first.

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py#L139

Comment: Just like there's no easy way to add a node to a fully connected layer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the `num_embeddings` after initializing the embedding. However, maybe you could concatenate the embedding weights to a new tensor to form a new weight tensor which extends the vocabulary.

I hope this example helps:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# if values in input are not in the interval [0, 4] an error is thrown
embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings = 5, embedding_dim = 3)

# input values can now be in the interval [0, 5]
embedding.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.cat((embedding.weight, torch.randn(1, 3))))

input = torch.LongTensor([[1, 5], [4, 3]])
```

Similarly you could add more than one new vocabulary by changing **n** in `torch.rand(n, 3)`.